# How to detect when a SWT Shell is being dragged to a new location on the screen

Tags: shell, swt, screen, move, drag

I am a newbie to SWT, but I have been unable to detect when my Shell begins being dragged by the user to a new location on the screen. I can get a controlMoved event when the dragging has been completed, but that is too late because I want to take some actions when the movement begins. I thought of trying to detect when the mouse was pressed in the shell Title Bar and then when it was subsequently released, but I have not found a way to detect that either. I am working on OSX with Cocoa.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Brian McGann

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure this is possible. The only events that seem to get fired when you select the title bar to move the shell are FocusOut events...
What sort of actions do you want to take when the movement begins?